# Where is the '^]' character on an AZERTY (French) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, terminal

Same question as [this one on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/377739/where-is-the-character-on-an-azerty-keyboard): where is telnet's escape character, `^]` located on an AZERTY (French) keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-$`

Mnemonic: the `$` key is where `]` would be on a QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question is already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/398/how-to-send-the-escape-character-on-os-x-terminal)

In the top rated answer, it says that it is  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

And if you have more questions, he also mentioned more keyboards with it.

Comment: Whoops. How do I close this question as duplicate?

Comment: I think you need to call a moderator by flagging. Or just delete it.

Comment: You can't flag this as a duplicate of a question on a different site. You could just leave this here, since it's specific to OS X. Arguably the other could be closed as off topic in favor of this one. Or, you could delete your question.

Comment: @ Chris Page, I am unable to delete the question since it has answers. I'll just leave it then.